# Javac - Compile .java files in different directories

Tags: java, javac

I'm creating a Submission System where I would like the Framework files in a fixed location on the server - a user will upload their file in a different directory.

If I'm just working with .class files, then the following command works when executed:

> java -cp 
>   /SubmissionSystem/Java/Assessment/Framework:/SubmissionSystem/Java/Assessment/Test
>   Assessment4

I was wondering whether there is a similar command that can be called to compile the .java files in different directories instead of .class files!

I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: javac ? used -d option to specify where you want to store the compiled files, -source path to specify where to get .java files from and class path as above ... http://www.herongyang.com/Java-Tools/javac-Java-Compilation-Command-and-Options.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, just replace `java` with `javac` and instead of passing the folder with the sources to the `-classpath` option, pass it to `-sourcepath`:

```
javac -cp /SubmissionSystem/Java/Assessment/Framework -sourcepath "/SubmissionSystem/Java/Assessment/Test Assessment4"
```

Don't forget proper quoting when the paths contain spaces. That will compile the files in place (so they will mix with the .java source files). You can let `javac` write them to a new place using the option `-d`

Comment: @Day:You can give UpVote to Aaron..!

Comment: @mdhar9e I cant until I get 15 reputation :(?